# How to count value in Python-Django website

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have the number of sales and the number of returns. I need to display the percentage of non-returned items in `safetycoef`. For example, there are 500 sales and 100 returns, it must be 80% in 'safetycoef'. Or 1000 sales and 240 returns, it means 76%. How to implement it?

html:

```
<div>
  {% for phone in object_list %}
        <div class="smartphone" >
            {% endif %}
            <p>{{ phone.title }} — reliabilty {{phone.safetycoef }}%</p>
            <p>Based on {{phone.sales }} sales and {{phone.returns }} returns </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your logic inside Python. The template is not the right place for this.

In your example, you're looping through multiple phones and want the percentage of the respective phone non-returned items.

I would declare a method on the model and call this inside your template:

```py
# models.py

class Phone(models.Model):
    # your attributes here
    # ...

    def get_reliability_percentage(self):
        return (1 - (self.returns / self.sales)) * 100
```

Then you can call this method inside your template:

```html
<div>
  {% for phone in object_list %}
        <div class="smartphone" >
            {% endif %}
            <p>{{ phone.title }} — reliabilty {{ phone.get_reliability_percentage }}%</p>
            <p>Based on {{phone.sales }} sales and {{phone.returns }} returns </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I had some problems, but now I fixed it. Your solution is easy and it works! You really saved my time. I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: I am sorry for another question, but may be you can find answer quickly. How to order these div's by this get_reliability_percentage? Usually I use in class like 'ordering = ['sales']'. But how to do it now?

Comment: @Toast Because the value is calculated only when requested and not saved anywhere, you would have to loop through all the phones, calculate their reliability percentage and then sort according to the percentage. I would do this in your view and then return the sorted list back to your template.

Comment: @Toast Another option would be to override the `save` method on your model, and save the reliability percentage to a database field every time you create a new phone or a phone gets updated. Then you can let the database order on that field.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to calculate it in the view and then send it inside the context. You can also calculate it in the html, but it's not that easy.

Comment: For me it's the fastest way. How can I do?

Comment: You have the function in view like this (I assume you're not using clase based views):

```
def function_view(request)
 returns = 240 (I guess you bring it from DB)
 sales = 1000
 safetycoef = 1 - sales / returns

    context = {
 'returns': returns,
 'sales': sales,
 'safetycoef': safetycoef
 }

    return render(request,'main/myhtml.html', context)

```
I hope it helps